# Using the Disk Utility application as SUDO user in Unity or on CLI

Tags: disk, software-recommendation

How do I start the "Disk Utility" program as sudo user, in the Unity gui?
If I want to start the application from a CLI, what is the application name?

(There is no reference to the actual program name in the "About" box, and typing "Disk Utility" or "disk utility" or "gnome-disk-utility" does not start the application!)

Comment: Not sure why you'd want to run this as root, but if you do use gksudo for GUI apps instead of sudo.

Answer (score 8):

You want `palimpsest`.

---

How did I find this out? I went to the folder `/usr/share/applications` and right clicked on Disk Utility, selecting Properties.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

just adding to the previous answer, if you prefix 'gksu' before 'palimpsest' in the Command field, it will automatically open as root, requiring your password. ( this can only be edited as root, so from the CLI you could 'gksu nautilus' to change this file. )

it took me awhile to figure that out, i was trying to add a 'gksu' option in the desktop file itself. this was much easier. i prefer the security of this method, to avoid borking a disk accidentally.

Comment: Could you instead of "add" to the other answer, make your answer self-contained? Or edit the other answer and add corrections.

Answer (score 1):

Check that the gnome-disk-utility package is installed and just run

`sudo gnome-disks` in your terminal